# I would like to put a binary masking vector on the tensor 3D in the tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, binary, mask

I would like to put a binary masking vector on the tensor 3D in the tensor flow.

For example, `shape=(None, 3,4,1)`

```
[[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10,11,12]]
```

I want to put a masking vector like

```
[[1,1,1,1] [1,1,1,1] [1,1,0,0]]
```

=> my ideal result is

```
[[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10,0,0]]
```

I try it as follow.

```
output = tf.layers.conv2d(output, 1, [5, 5], strides=(9, 6), padding='valid')
output = tf.tanh(output)
aa = [1.0] * 10 + [0.0] *2
aa = aa * batch_size
bb = tf.constant(aa , shape =(batch_size , 3,4,1))
output = output * bb
```

I want to put a mask vector behind the output.

```py
output = tf.layers.conv2d(output, 1, [5, 5], strides=(9, 6), padding='valid')
output = tf.tanh(output)

## output shape is (batch size , 3,4,1)
## and then mask vector [[1,1,1,1] [1,1,1,1] [1,1,0,0]] 3x4 
## (batch size , mask vector , 1)
## (batch size, 3, 4, 1)
# I want to put a mask vector behind the output.
# Include any research you've conducted
```

I like this

```
masking = tf.sequence_mask([27]*19 + [17] , maxlen=27, dtype=tf.float32)
masking2 = tf.expand_dims(masking,axis = 0)
masking2 = tf.expand_dims(masking2,axis = -1)
mask = tf.tile(masking2, [batch_size, 1 , 1,1])
G = G * mask
```

Answer (score 1):

[tf.sequence_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) should do what you need.

In your particular example it would be `tf.sequence_mask([4, 4, 2], maxlen=4, dtype=tf.float32)`.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked. It'll be helpful for others that come by this question.